# Manual Immediate Airflow Dag Refresh / Scan

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

Is there an Airflow v2 api endpoint or [gcloud composer v2 cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer) I can hit to immediately trigger a refresh / scan for new/updated files?

Airflow by default scans the DAGs directory every [5 minutes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-dir-list-interval) for new files.

Airflow v1 had a "Refresh" button and endpoint:

[image]

This refresh functionality was [removed in v2.5.1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/release_notes.html#webserver-dag-refresh-buttons-removed).

For context, I'm developing in [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-overview) testing uploading dags to a GCP bucket and it would be great if I could "gcp cp ... && hit_endpoint.sh" so I don't have to ever wait -- I could just set `dag_dir_list_interval` time to be very low but that could be inefficient for the majority of time that I'm not playing around interactively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible currently, just change [dag_dir_list_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#triggerer) to be the minimal value 1 second.

---

There was discussion of adding this feature [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/17429) but was rejected because the webserver is stateless and does not have access to the DAG files.

The [Airflow cli](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#command-line-interface-and-environment-variables-reference) also has no documented way to trigger a dag refresh/rescan.

I verified that the [gcloud composer environments storage dags import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/storage/dags/import) also uses the same `dag_dir_list_interval` configuration and is no faster than otherwise adding a file to the dag bucket. There are no other relevant [gcloud composer cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments) options.

It would be nice if it just used pub sub on the bucket to immediately refresh, but for now setting `dag_dir_list_interval` to 1 second is ok.